# The Gaussian wave packet

Tags: quantum-mechanics

We have a Gaussian wave packet which is given by the equation:

### [image]

In the text book we are given some information of its features.

One of the is:

[image]

---

I am having trouble showing the proof for  P3.2, as i do not understand what we are doing when we do:

$\phi(p)->\phi(p)exp[\frac{-px_0}{\hbar}]$ .

Would anyone be able to derive the proof and so tell we what we achieve by doing this transformation

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\phi(p)$ is the momentum-space wavefunction. $|\phi(p)|^2$ is the probability distribution of momentum, and as it is the square of a magnitude, we can change the phase of the wavefunction by multiplying $\phi(p)$ by a phase factor (in this case $e^{-ipx_0/\hbar}$) without changing the way the particle behaves.

$\phi(x)$, the position-space wavefunction, is the inverse fourier transform of $\phi(p)$, so we can write this as
$$
\phi(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(p)e^{ipx/\hbar}dp.
$$
If we introduce the phase shift factor, this becomes
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(p)e^{ipx/\hbar}dp \rightarrow \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ip(x-x_0)/\hbar}\phi(p)dp.
$$
Hopefully you now see that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ip(x-x_0)/\hbar}\phi(p)dp = \phi(x-x_0).
$$
This is still a fourier transform, but now we have transformed the position by $x\rightarrow x-x_0$.